# Is it possible to use the AT command to create one-time-only tasks?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

After using the AT command several times, on several occasions, to run commands at a specified time just once, I now find that the old, expired tasks are still listed in Task Scheduler. What is the point of keeping tasks that have run in the past and are never going to run again? Is it possible to get these tasks to autodelete once they've finished? I.e. without having to come back later and run AT job-id /DELETE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use the `schtasks` command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of `at`.  It lets you specify a task to run once explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was a solution involving the much simpler-to-use AT command, but I see I can use schtasks with the /Z option to do what I want, although it's harder to remember the syntax.